# asterisk random generation using rand in php

Tags: php

```
$r = array(
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
array('.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','*','.','*','.','.','.','.','*','.','*','.'),
);

foreach ($r as $value)
{
$value = rand(0,19);
if ($value<=19)
    {
    $r[$value]++;
    }
}
print_r($r);
```

I have tried mt_rand as well but that doesn't help as well but it doesnt get random at all. Also is there a way to simplify this code instead of writing array every time. Also can I make it in a box form using  thanks

Comment: trying to use arrays to create and store a minefield on a 20 x 20 grid. Place ten mines randomly on the grid, then display the grid, using asterisks (* ) for the mines and periods (. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function generateRandomString($length = 20) {
$characters = '.....*...***..***.*.*';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
return $randomString;
}
for ($i = 0; $i <20; $i++)
{
echo generateRandomString();
echo "<br>";
}
```

Did this, got the required answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here's something that outputs something similar to your arrays.

```
    <?php
    // Config
    $rows = 20;
    $cols = 20;
    $mines = 100;

    // Error checking
    if ( ($rows * $cols) <= $mines ) {
        die("Error: There are too many mines to fit on this minefield!");
    }

    // How many spaces are not occupied by mines?
    $not_mines = ($rows * $cols) - $mines;

    // Build a string like "....***", with length corresponding to rows/cols/mines.
    $mine_string = str_repeat('.', $not_mines);
    $mine_string.= str_repeat('*', $mines);

    // Randomize the string.
    $mine_string = str_shuffle($mine_string);

    // Display the string in rows/column format
    for ( $y = 0; $y < $rows; $y++ ) {
        for ( $x = 0; $x < $cols; $x++ ) {
            // the position of the string to take a character from
            $pos = ($y * $cols) + $x; 

            // get one character from the string
            echo substr($mine_string, $pos, 1);
        }

        // End of a row, break to new column
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

Output (different every time):

```
....*..**......*.*.*
.*.........*.***...*
.*..**......**.*....
.......*.*....***...
**....**...**.......
.......*..**.**.....
*.*....*.....*.*...*
....**.....**...*.*.
.*...*....*.*..*..*.
..*......**.*....**.
*..*...*...........*
.*..*...*........*..
.....*..........*..*
.***..*..***........
...*.....***........
***...........*..*..
.*...*..*.....*.*...
....*.......*.*...*.
.............**.....
...*........**...*..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$size = 20;
$count_mines = 10;
$one_dimensial_map = array_fill(0, $count_mines, '*') + array_fill(0, $size * $size, '.');
shuffle($one_dimensial_map);
$two_dimensial_map = array_chunk($one_dimensial_map, $size);
print_r(array_map('json_encode', $two_dimensial_map)); // just for output
```